# Display of Double Precision Floating Points Vs Their comparrison

Tags: c++

### Preamble

I am looking into a system developed to be used by people who don't understand  floating point arithmetic. For this reason the implementation of comparison for floating point numbers is not exposed to the people using the system. Currently comparisons of floating point numbers occur like this (And this **cannot** change due to legacy reasons):

```
// If either number is not finite, do default comparison
if (!IsFinite(num1) || !IsFinite(num2)) {
    output = (num1 == num2);
} else {
    // Get exponents of both numbers to determine epsilon for comparison
    tmp = (OSINT32*)&num1+1;
    exp1 = (((*tmp)>>20)& 0x07ff) - 1023;
    tmp = (OSINT32*)&num2+1;
    exp2 = (((*tmp)>>20)& 0x07ff) - 1023;

    // Check if exponent is the same
    if (exp1 != exp2) {
        output = false;
    } else {
        // Calculate epsilon based on the magic number 47 (presumably calculated experimentally)?
        epsilon = pow(2.0,exp1-47);
        output = (fabs(num2-num1) <= eps);
    }
}
```

The crux of it is, we calculate the epsilon based on the exponent of the number to stop users of the interface from making floating point comparison mistakes. **A BIG NOTE**: This is for people who are not software programmers so when they do `pow(sqrt(2), 2) == 2` they don't get a big surprise. Maybe this is not the best idea, but like i said, it cannot be changed.

### The Problem

We are having trouble figuring out how to display numbers to the user. In the past they simply displayed the number to 15 significant digits. But this results in problems of the following type:

```
>> SHOW 4.1 MOD 1
>>    0.099999999999999996
>> SHOW (4.1 MOD 1) == 0.1
>>    TRUE
```

The comparison calls this correct because of the generated epsilon. But the printing of the number is confusing for people, how is `0.099999999999999996 = 0.1`?. **We need a way to show the number such that it represents the shortest number of significant bits to which a number compared to it would be TRUE.** So for 0.099999999999999996 this would be 0.1, for 0.569999999992724327 it would be 0.569999999992725.

Is this possible?

Comment: If you can't change the underlying logic, I can't see a way of doing this that doesn't "fudge" the results for display.

Comment: Honestly, I think this effort is doomed to fail. I think you're attempting something that can't be done perfectly. And the closer to perfect it is, the more dangerous that people will expect it to be perfect when it cannot be and the more harm the rare cases where it does the unexpected will do. If you have some very specific use case this satisfies, maybe this makes sense. But if you just think that it's easy to do floating point better than what the world's top experts have produced because all the quirks can be easily worked around, ...

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I am not trying to best floating point. The question is pretty clear, the objective is to hide floating point comparison errors from users who are *not* software engineers. Our current solution is to just clip the precision which works just fine. I am trying to make it better though. If you have anything actually constructive you should add an answer ...

Comment: @ColinBasnett Fudging the display results is pretty much the only solution i would say.

Comment: "Floating point comparison errors" - this is a fundamental misunderstanding. If two floating-point values don't compare equal it's because they **aren't** equal. Pretending that they are doesn't solve the problem. It just hides the symptoms, until they pop up somewhere else. Welcome to Whack-a-Mole! Next issue: A equals B and B equals C, but A does not equal C!

Comment: @PeteBecker I am not arguing that point, I am trying to improve legacy software. In order to ensure older programs remain compatible the part that I said cannot be changed, ... Cannot be changed. So until we decide to drop this section and rewrite it (which I hope is soon) I can't do anything about it. I can try and make the experience more fluid for the users though.

Comment: Maybe the [Fixed-Point Real Numbers](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2016/p0037r1.html) proposal can be helpful for you if it is approved.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster: That still suffers from the finite bits, infinite real numbers problem. Also, part of the problem here is backwards compatibility.

Comment: I had this problem in one of my apps, and decided to store all numbers as decimals `mantissa * 10^exponent`. Then all calculations become calculations on integers and the displayed value matches the internal one exactly.

Comment: @MSalters oh, sadly it doesn't help :( but as fixed-point aritmethics it would solve the rounding problems at least?

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster: Nope; `(1/3)*3` still rounds the fractional part, as `1/3 = 0.1010101... binary`, an infinite string.

Comment: @MSalters then I should dive more into the proposal, I've misunderstood the whole thing.

Comment: @PeteBecker Also after looking over my question, i never said "Floating point comparison errors" I said "Floating point comparison mistakes" as in the mistake of comparing floating point numbers, which is in almost any case, doing it. I can think of almost no scenarios where doing `float a == float b` and not `fabs(float a - float b) < eps` is a good idea.

Comment: @Ben - you said "floating point comparison errors" in the comment that prompted my reply. You're right that "floating point comparison mistakes" is much more clearly about misunderstandings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could calculate `(num - pow(2.0, exp - 47))` and `(num + pow(2.0, exp - 47))`, convert both to string and search the smallest decimal between the range.

The exact value of a double is `mantissa * pow(2.0, exp - 51)` with an integer value `mantissa`, so if you add/subtract `pow(2.0, exp - 47)` you change the mantissa by `2^4`, which should be exactly representable without rounding errors (unless in corner cases where the mantissa under/overflows, i.e if it is binary `<= pow(2,4)` or `>= pow(2, 53) - pow(2,4)`. you might want to check for these*).

Then you have two strings, search the first position where the digits differ and cut it off there. Although there are a lot of rounding cases, especially when you not just want a correct number in the range, but the number closes to the input number (but that might not be needed). For example if you get `"1.23"` and `"1.24"`, you might even want to output `"1.235".

---

This also shows that your example is wrong. epsilon for `0.569999999992724327` is (to maximal precision) `0.000000000000003552713678800500929355621337890625`. The ranges are `0.569999999992720773889232077635824680328369140625` to `0.569999999992727879316589678637683391571044921875` and would be cut off at `0.569999999992725` (or `0.569999999992723` if you prefer that rounding)

---

An easier to implement sledgehammer method would be to output it to the maximal precision, cut one digit off, convert it back to double, check if it compares correctly. Then continue cutting, till the comparison fails. (could be improved with a binary search)

---

<sup>* They should still be exactly representable, but your comparison method will behave very odd. Consider `num1 == 1` and `num2 ==  1 - pow(2.0, -53) = 0.99999999999999988897769753748434595763683319091796875`. There difference `0.00000000000000011102230246251565404236316680908203125` is below your epsilon`0.000000000000003552713678800500929355621337890625`, but the comparison will say they differ, because they have different exponents</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it is good. I have fixed my example, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Alternatively, stringify the two numbers as described in the first paragraph, and print the length of their common prefix, _plus one_. I.e with `0.9942` and `0.9967` you'd print `0.995`.

Comment: @MSalters: Isn't that the same? The length of the common prefix plus one = first place where they differ. I actually implemented it once and only noticed a year later, that my implementation was sometimes wrong. Although I wanted a range with `<` instead of `<=`, so in a case of `(1.23999, 124000)` neither number was valid and the output had to become something like `1.239995`, which might have made it harder

Comment: @BeniBela: It's a minor variation, which is why I added it as a comment. The main design issue is what to print as the extra digit.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible.

```
double a=fmod(4.1,1);
cerr<<std::setprecision(0)<<a<<"\n";
cerr<<std::setprecision(10)<<a<<"\n";
cerr<<std::setprecision(20)<<a<<"\n";
```

produces:

```
0.1
0.1
0.099999999999999644729
```

I think you just need to determine what level of display precision corresponds to your epsilon value.

Comment: But the epsilon value is binary, not a decimal, so it want necessarily correspond to a decimal barrier of 0.1, 0.01, 0.0001 etc.

Comment: Yes, you could get false positives with this approach -- although they would be very rare if your precision is large enough.

Comment: True, but the corresponding precision that will completely avoid this is 14 Sig Figs. We already figured that out, just wanted to see if we could do better, because like you said, all but the rare occasions will be losing precision in the display.

Answer (score 0):

> We need a way to show the number such that it represents the shortest
>   number of significant bits to which a number compared to it would be
>   TRUE.

Can't you just do it the brute-force-ish way?

```
float num = 0.09999999;
for (int precision = 0; precision < MAX_PRECISION; ++precision) {
    std::stringstream str;
    float tmp = 0;
    str << std::fixed << std::setprecision(precision) << num;
    str >> tmp;
    if (num == tmp) {
        std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(precision) << num;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It is not possible to avoid confusing users given the constraints you've specified.  For one thing, 0.0999999999999996447 compares equal to 0.1, and 0.1000000000000003664 compares equal to 0.1, but 0.0999999999999996447 does not compare equal to 0.1000000000000003664.  For another, 2.00000000000001421 compares equal to 2.0, but 1.999999999999999778 does not compare equal to 2.0 even though it's much closer to 2.0 than 2.00000000000001421 is.

Enjoy.

Comment: Two people below have provided convincing arguments to the contrary. I suspect you need to defend this more than giving some number examples.

Comment: @Ben:  Perhaps the best is to just display the true comparison range. As number with the epsilon. Like `0.57 +- 0.000000000000003552713678800500929355621337890625` or `0.57 +- 3.5527137E-15`. Or as range `[min,max]` due to the exponent issue

Comment: @BeniBela I like the idea, but i don't think the people using the interpreter should know about this comparison. And more to the point they wouldn't care about it.

Comment: @Ben: Have you considered displaying the number at full precision, but blurring the last digits, so that they cannot be read?

Comment: @BeniBela Not something that we can do, only text is shown. I am not sure what the purpose of this would be either.

Comment: @Ben: So the users knows there might be more digits, but that they do not count. Next idea: White text on white background

Comment: @BeniBela I get where you are coming from but i dont think showing this will be helpful, i would rather just cut it off at 14 digits if i cannot display a number that is accurate.